# Modifiers can't be applied due to being deactivated

Tags: modifiers

running Blender 2.91.2 and am having two different blend files in which modifiers cannot be applied due to them being "disabled" and cannot be applied to Multi-User data. They work just fine, hell I even just created an array modifier and with the untouched, base settings the modifier is disabled. Am a bit PO right now because deadline is tomorrow. Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Which modifier is causing you trouble? Some can't be applied due to missing settings (ie shrink-wrap without a selected target), in which case you will get the "modifier deactivated, skipping apply" message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Late to the party on this one. (I was asleep when the question was posted!)

[image]

In future, there's a quick way to get over this problem.

Go to the Object Data Properties tab (green triangle). In the Mesh data line you'll see a number next to the shield

[image]

Hovering the mouse over the number will show the following popup

[image]

Click on that number to make it disappear and you'll then be able to apply the modifier.

Answer (score 0):

Have found the solution with help of someone else. There were old objects hidden that the newly created Array modifier somehow got connected to (??) I deleted those since I didn't use them anymore and now everything works fine.